# Ember-Simple-Auth OAuth 2.0 not sending the right parameters

Tags: javascript, ember.js, oauth, ember-simple-auth

So I am setting up `ember-simple-auth` using the `OAuth 2.0` extension. The issue is whenever I try to login and look at what's being sent as form data, it's only sending the `grant_type` and `password` parameter. However, the `password` parameter is always empty, and sometimes it doesn't even show up. The `username` parameter is always missing, I haven't seen it thus far.

Here is my `login.hbs` code (btw I am using ember-cli)

```
<form {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
  <label for="identification">Login</label>
  {{input class="form-control" id='identification' placeholder='Enter Login' value=identification}}
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  {{input class="form-control" id='password' placeholder='Enter Password' type='password' value=password}}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

My `login.js` code in `controllers`

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
  authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant'
});
```

My `application.js` code in `controllers`

```
// app/routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin);
```

In my `config/environment.js` file

```
if (environment === 'development') {
  …
  ENV['simple-auth-oauth2'] = {
    serverTokenEndpoint: '/api/v1/oauth/token'
  }
  …
}
```

`It's making the call to the right url after this change`

In my initializers folder

```
// app/initializers/simple-auth-config.js
export default {
  name:       'simple-auth-config',
  before:     'simple-auth',
  initialize: function() {
    window.ENV = FrontENV;
  }
};
```

It's pretty easy to notice that most of this code is copied from the tutorial on `simplelabs` with some customizations. However, I can't figure out why the parameters aren't being sent correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You posted more or less the same question on the Ember Simple Auth issue tracker and got some help there already. Is this solved? If so, could you add the answer here and mark it as solved?

Comment: I'll get right on that.

Comment: A month have passed... :)

Answer (score 1):

The missing parameters are `client_id` and `client_secret`.  Ember-Simple-Auth OAuth 2.0 doesn't include these, as they are not secret when used in an ember app.  You need to create a custom authenticator like this to include both parameters:

```js
//app/authenticators/mine.js
import Authenticator from 'simple-auth-oauth2/authenticators/oauth2';

export default Authenticator.extend({
    makeRequest: function(url, data) {
        data.client_id = '…';
        data.client_secret = '…';
        return this._super(url, data);
    }
});
```

You can use it like the OAuth 2.0 Authenticator by replacing `simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant` with `authenticator:mine`.

In the following are the rest of the files for a working example.

```js
//app/controllers/login.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
    authenticator: 'authenticator:mine'
});
```

```js
//app/routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(
    ApplicationRouteMixin
);
```

```js
//app/routes/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(
    AuthenticatedRouteMixin
);
```

```js
//app/routes/login.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import UnauthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/unauthenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(
    UnauthenticatedRouteMixin
);
```

```html
<!-- app/templates/application.hbs -->
{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
  <h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
  <a {{ action 'invalidateSession' }}>Logout</a>
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}
```

```html
<!-- app/templates/index.hbs -->
<p>Private page</p>
```

```html
<!-- app/templates/login.hbs -->
<form {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
  <label for="identification">Login</label>
  {{input value=identification placeholder='Enter Login'}}
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  {{input value=password placeholder='Enter Password' type='password'}}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

```js
//config/environment.js
(…)

ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:oauth2-bearer'
}

ENV['simple-auth-oauth2'] = {
    serverTokenEndpoint: '/api/v1/oauth/token'
}

(…)
```

This answer is derived from the comments on the mentioned [question on the Ember Simple Auth issue tracker](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/226).

Comment: If you're using a recent version of Ember CLI (I think 0.1.5 and newer) the authenticator will automatically be registered with the container as `'authenticators:mine'` and you don't need the extra initializer. Also the localStorage session store is the default so you don't need to configure that in `config/environment.js`.

Comment: Actually it's `'authenticator:mine'`. Thanks!

Comment: how do you change the `identification` param name to be called `username` instead (as required by parse)